# Como manter página atualizada sem refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou tentando criar uma página que fique sempre atualizada, sem ter que dar *refresh*.

Criei uma função em Javascript que fica buscando um `select` e `while` de outra página, mas isso esta gerando alto consumo no CPU e os caras do servidor já reclamaram. Como faço para sempre dar `select` em Javascript sem ter esse problema?

```html
<!---- função que chama a pagina onde tem o while ----->
<script type="application/javascript">
function busca (){
        var numero1 = $("#n1").val();
        var numero2 = $("#n2").val();
        $.post("busca_p.php", {n1:numero1, n2:numero2}, function(retorno){
            $(".msg_porto").html(retorno);
            });

        };

</script>

<script>
   window.setInterval(busca,1000);// coloquei este para ativar a funlção a cada 1 segundo 
</script>
```

Chama a página `busca_p.php` que tem um `select` e `while`  e carrega dentro da `div (msg_porto)`.

Funciona bem, mas fica processando o tempo todo e já reclamaram de alto uso de CPU por parte do servidor.

Comment: Pessoal talvez baguncei um pouco o que tentei passar, mas o que tento fazer é ter minha pagina atualizada sempre sem precisar atualizar a pagina, então fiz uma função que chama uma pagina onde esta consultando o banco e dando um while . Assim traz o resultado e carrega na div (msg_porto).  E ate funciona mas consome muito cpu do servidor porque coloquei a função window.setInterval(busca,1000); para chamar a função que solicita a pagina de consulta a cada 1 segundo.

Comment: O javascript faz a função de solicitar ao servidor às informações que serão retornadas pelo PHP sem ter que atualizar a página inteira. Dá uma conferida neste link
http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/atualizar-parte-do-site-sem-refresh-na-pagina-inteira-com-javascript espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Dario me ajudou sim , conhecimento é sempre bem vindo, mas preciso que minha pagina se atualize sem a necessidade da ação do usuario, e consegui isso apenas usando a função window.setInterval(busca,1000) , mas isso faz o servidor processar muito , pensei se poderia ter isto sem ter que acessar uma pagina off , mas posso estar falando bobeira, mas obrigado por tentar me ajudar

Comment: Qual é o código que estás a correr no servidor? podes colocar aqui? e qual é o HTML que está a retornar? Sem essa informação não podemos ajudar muito mais.

Comment: <div class="msg_porto">...</div>   //A div que retorna com o resultado

Comment: Usando o framework angular, talvez resolva seu problema, já que ele é dinâmico. Não sei usá-lo, mas quem conhece pode até te orientar melhor.

Comment: Use Web Socket para isso, aparentemente o que você quer é ter um real-time em sua aplicação e Web Socket ajuda a resolver justamente esse problema e com um consumo bem menor de CPU, segue uma boa introdução: http://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: @AndréNascimento, acredito que o Angular por si só não resolva o problema dele, afinal ele ainda vai precisar consultar o servidor para atualizar o modelo. por um outro lado, pode ser que exista algo em PHP que faça o que o MeteorJS faz, um bind do Model ligando o client ao server.

Comment: @CesarLimaPaulo, O conteudo novo é criado pela sua aplicação? digo, um outro usuario acessa uma outra pagina do sistema de insere os dados novos? se sim, você pode usar Web Sockets para notificar todos os clientes que precisam desta informação nova.

Answer (score 3):

A sua actualização de página nada tem de mal, o problema está no lado do servidor. Claro que pode ser melhorado, mas o principio é o que usa.

A chamada de `Ajax` está bem realizada e serve o propósito. No lado do servidor a única coisa que pode falhar são os consequentes `requests`, muito em especial as consultas à base de dados. Um problema recorrente.

É comum muitos ambientes disporem apenas de um servidor, onde o mesmo serve de  `Http Server` e `Sql Server`, mas dependendo do projecto e da base de dados isto pode ser um problema (*o que normalmente é*).

Nesse princípio, cada `request HTTP` pode utilizar muitos recursos do servidor, conforme a sua implementação parece fazer. Para minimizar este problema, aconselho-o a recorrer à utilização de `cache`. Seja ela mediante software próprio ou um esquema por si idealizado que possa guardar o resultado do seu último `SELECT` à base de dados.

> **Algo a evitar são comandos SELECT generalistas '*' no SQL**, limitando ao máximo o número de registos a retornar.

Na programação não basta apenas colocar uns comandos, temos de pensar a implementação como um todo, mas muito em especial o fim a que se destina e a quantidade de dados que o mesmo vai gerir e movimentar em cada `request`.

Para finalizar, vale dizer que do lado do cliente você pode fazer e refazer seguindo inúmeras recomendações... mas enquanto do lado do servidor as coisas não estejam preparadas para a realidade do projecto, nada irá ser solução.

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente não é uma consulta muito levo no lado do servidor, as tabelas onde são realizadas a consulta é alimentada a cada segundo?
Primeiro seria bom aumentar o tempo de consulta, invés de 1 seg coloque 10 ou 5 ou até 1 min, isto depende da periodicidade que as tabelas são atualizadas. 
Web Sockets é  uma boa, caso não precise funcionar em navegadores antigos (principalmente nos IEs antigos).
Algo que iria te ajudar bastante seria criar uma outra tabela que armazena a data e hora da ultima atualização das tabelas que fazem parte desta consulta, dai ao invés de a cada 1 seg efetuar a consulta, você consulta primeiro nesta tabela e se houver alguma atualização dai sim você consulta realiza esta sua consulta, isto vai diminuir bastante o processamento do servidor.